# How to transfer control between threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question, and I couldn't find its answer after googling it for quite some time.
I intend to create a browser application. What i want is that when the main method runs i consider it the main browser application and the user has now the option of opening multiple tabs. A thread will be started each time a tab is opened and all the tabs will close when the main application closes.Each tab(thread) will run independently and the user has the option to switch tabs, the previous tab keeps on doing what is it doing while the user works in the new tab and the user can open as many tabs as he wants.
here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass 
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input="abc";
        String check="true";

        while (check=="true")
        {
            System.out.println("if you want to open new tab write yes");
            input=in.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("yes"))
            {
                System.out.println("if check");
                Thread tab = new myThread();
                tab.start();
                check="true";
            }
            else
            {
                check="false";
                System.out.println("else check");
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}

public class myThread extends Thread 
{
    public myThread()
    {
        setDaemon(true);                                                                                                        
    }

    public void run()
    {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("one thread started");

            System.out.println("enter url to search\n");

            String input=in.nextLine();

    }
}
```

My problem is that when the user wishes to open the thread, it opens, completes its task and rather then waiting to take input from the user it goes back to main . What I want is that the user should have the option to switch between tabs. When a user opens a tab he stays on that tab even if he is doing nothing and when he wants to switch to another tab he can do that.
how do i give full control to a thread or how do i sleep() the main thread until the user is working on a new thread and when the user wishes to go back to the main thread he can do that?is taht possible?

Comment: there's a `yield` method that may help. by the way, i highly recomm. the cave of programming concurrency tutorial

Comment: I wouldn't encourage you to schedule your threads manually because this often introduces performance problems and other mysterious bugs. I'd suggest you to rethink your architecture and think about the GUI/tabs/etc as one thread and other threads as workers that keep your application state up to date in the background.

Comment: I would actually not use threads at all. Multiple tabs don't operate in parallel, they operate in sequence and a single thread can do that already. What you have in parallel is "state" but that's why there are objects where each instance has it's own state.

Comment: what should i do then ? all the knowledge i have about threads is from a book by ivor horton , when i google i do not get anythingg related to my problem or any thing that could help me solve my problem?suggest me a topic that i could read

Comment: Although it can be done sequentially indeed, the question was about how to create a browser using separate threads for each tab.

Comment: of what i know @zapl is that a browser is a multithreaded application ? is that not so?google chrome is multithreaded browser

Comment: You could use a worker thread approach where the main thread accepts input from the user and the execution of the task is deferred to a worker thread.

Comment: but i want each tab(thread) to work independently , and i want the user to have the choice of which tab to choose among other open tabs? what should i do about it?

Comment: Of course if you want you can create separate threads for separate tabs. The main thread then should post the task to the associated thread. To make this feasible, you need to maintain a list of tabs along with their associated threads.

Comment: I completely agree with @ExtremeCoders, that's what is done with all GUI toolkit that i know, be it in java or any other language. Besides, even if you do not see a tab,  it can make sense to keep a thread for it tab if you need to perform some computation for this tab.

Comment: allright ,but how will i transfer control to that particular thread for which a task has just come , my problem is that when i am opening a thread ,the loop in the main is completing its execution first and then the coommands in run are executing how do i transfer full control to the thread which i just started?

Comment: The most important point is if you let multiple threads read input directly it will all be chaos. If you look at any UI toolkit you will see that only a single thread accesses the UI. It reads the events, post them to a message queue, the events from this queue may be processed by other secondary threads. The secondary threads never access the UI directly.

Comment: so how do create a message queue (which i guess should be maintained by the main thread) from which other threads(tabs) read from?or how do i send a task from the main thread intended for a particular thread to that thread?

Comment: A "Tab" is not a "Thread". Start modelling your application without threads. Once you have a model that works on a single thread you can find parts that can be done in a background thread to allow e.g. downloading the HTTP data while the user can click buttons.

Comment: i want a tab to be a thread ,thats the task i have , i design my application that way, now the main thread has started ,and now the user opens a new tab(thread) ,as this thread opens ,the main stops ,the user has a url bar in the tab he started where he can type an address,is that possible?

Comment: Many of the answers to your questions are covered in [the concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a basic mistake within your code is that the `check=="true"` condition is always `false`.

You can solve it quickly by changing it to `check.equals("true")`, but you might as well fix it properly:

- Change `String check` to `boolean check`
- Change `"false"` to `false`
- Change `"true"` to `true`

Second, here is my suggestion for a general threading-scheme:

**Step #1** - Instead of extending the `Thread` class, implement the `Runnable` interface:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    public MyClass(String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getOutput()
    {
        return output;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        ...
        output = ...;
    }

    private String input  = null;
    private String output = null;
}
```

**Step #2** - Save all the threads in a list, start each of the threads, and then join each of the threads:

```
public static ArrayList<String> run(ArrayList<String> inputs,long maxMillisPerThread)
{
    ArrayList<MyClass> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    ArrayList<Thread>  threads   = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    ArrayList<String>  outputs   = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String input : inputs)
    {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass(input);
        Thread  thread   = new Thread(myObject);
        myObjects.add(myObject);
        threads.add(thread);
        thread.start();
    }
    for (Thread thread : threads)
    {
        try
        {
            thread.join(maxMillisPerThread);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
        }
    }
    for (MyClass myObject : myObjects)
    {
        outputs.add(myObject.getOutput());
    }
    return outputs;
}
```

**Step #3** - Create the input you want for each thread, and pass it to the function above. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<...; i++)
    inputs.add(...);

ArrayList<String> outputs = run(inputs,3000);
for (String output : outputs)
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: i dont simply under stand our code or what is is doing and how it would help me solve my problem , secondly my loop seems to be working fine

Comment: My general suggestion is to implement `interface Runnable` instead of extending `class Thread`, save all the threads that you create in a list of threads, start all the threads one by one, and then join all the threads one by one. But I will remove this post if it's not helping you.

Comment: sorry if i am being sracastic but i dont think you are getting my point ,or i might not be clear enough ,

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a suggestion for a general threading-scheme, rather than a specific solution to your problem. I have added a description line above each of the coding blocks provided in the answer. And as I mentioned in the previous comment, if it's completely unhelpful to your needs then I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have one one "main" thread, which is generally the only one that will be used for UI operations (painting components, handling user input, etc.). You will have to use this thread for all your tab, at least for UI operations.

What you can have though is one thread for each tab, that would be used for whatever *computing* operation you have to do for this tab (that is, almost everything except drawing to the screen). You don't need to "switch" between threads, they run concurrently, you only need some sort of communication mechanism between your main thread and these tab threads. What to use for this communication mostly depends on the UI stack you are using (swing ? android ? other ?) .

The Main thread always has some kind of run-loop mechanism (provided by the GUI toolkit) that you can use to post events ant actions to be run on this thread. There are thread communication utilities in java, but as you're speaking of UI and tabs, you really need to know which toolkit you are developing for and use its own mechanisms. For Swing, for example, you would use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [SwingUtilities#invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: how do i access the main thread and how do i use the main thread to send a message to a thread that was created by the main thread?

Comment: and i am not using any UI stack right now ,i just want the   main thread to send a task to a particular thread among other threads?

Comment: what i actually want is to switch between threads ,is that possible?
a user has opened multiple threads when given the choice ,lets say 4 threads.now he want to go to thread 2 ,how do i do that?

Comment: Well you don't actually need to do that ; the point with threasd is that they run concurrently. When your user switch tab, so will your UI thread (main thread), displaying the current tab and handling input events for it. But your other threads will continue running, and I believe that's what you really want as you wrote "the previous tab keeps on doing what is it doing while the user works in the new tab". Concerning the main thread communication, I'll edit my answer.